# Challenging issue how to find rules between strings?

Tags: python, string, crossword

I have a project related Lindenmayer system. I have stuck on something due to the algorithm. I would like to create a rule finder between two strings such as
Gen1:
A B A A B A B A
Gen2:
A B A A B A B A A B A A B

The output should be:
rule1: A, AB
rule2: B, A

This rule should be used for any strings which have relationship.

I created some methods they find constants in the strings such as: "A", "B"
However, I do not know how to find rules.

```
  def compare(newcode, trialrule1, trialrule2):

        if newcode==Genx2:
            print('rules are tru')
            print(trialrule1)
            print(trialrule2)
            sys.exit()
        else:

            return newcode, trialrule1, trialrule2


def rulefinder():

 rul1 = Genx2[0]
 rul2 = Genx2[1]
 code = ""
 for y in range(1,len(Genx2)-1):
     for x in range (0,len(Genx2)-1):


                for cha in Genx1:
                    if cha==repetitivestring1[0]:

                        code +=AddingToNewString2(rul1)


                    elif cha==repetitivestring1[1]:

                        code +=AddingToNewString2(rul2)


                print(code)
                compare(code, rul1, rul2)
                rul1=AddingToNewString2(Genx2[x+1])

     rul2=AddingToNewString2(Genx2[y+1])

def AddingToNewString2(rules):
   NewString = ""

   NewString = NewString + rules

   return NewString
```

Comment: Try adding what you have tried so far. If you have tried nothing, try something and then come back and edit this question.

Comment: Okay, I shared the codes. Thank you